# Check if specified time is mentioned in an incremented time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, math

Here are some of the variables I have:

```
start time: 10:45
interval time: 5 (in minutes)
specific time: 14:20
```

I need to find out if the specific time lands exactly on any of the times incremented from the start time.

For example, the interval time is 5.

```
10:45 incremented by interval time
11:00
11:05
11:10
...
14:20 << specific time found

if(specificTime is mentioned in any of the incremented times) {
    console.log('Found it!');
} else {
    console.log('Not found');
}
```

But this is hard when the start time is `10:48` and the interval time is 5 minutes. Because:

```
10:48
10:53
10:58
11:03
11:08
...
```

and `14:20` is not mentioned in this one, so it would log "Not found".

How can I find out if the specific times is mentioned in the incremented times from the start time?

The interval time will not always be 5 and the other variables will be dynamic as well.

I am **NOT** looking to use loops. There has to be a formula or function that can help me achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to know if the minutes is a multiple of `5`? `date.getMinutes() % 5 === 0`

Comment: @p.s.w.g In the first example, the minutes will end in 5 or 0 because the start time is 10:45. But in the second example, the start time is 10:48. Also, the interval will not always be 5. If it's 7 or 22, for example, it will change everything up. I'm just trying to see if there's some kind of math or formula for this

Comment: If you're doing date/time calculations you should consider working with [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/guides/), or at least work in _milliseconds since the epoch_ as numeric values --  `new Date().getTime()` -- instead of working with Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can calculate if it is possible to perform a restless division of the difference between the start time and the specified time and the interval.

Depending on the scale of your time intervals, you can calculate this in hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds or basically any scale. Since your examples deal in minutes, the code snippet also does.

Note that this snippet assumes both times are within the same day (00:00 - 24:00) and that the specific time is later within that day than the start time. I'll let you figure out the rest :)

```js
function toMinutes(hours, minutes) {
  return (hours * 60) + minutes;
}

const startTime = toMinutes(10, 45);
const specificTime = toMinutes(14, 20);
const interval = toMinutes(0, 5);

const difference = specificTime - startTime;

if (difference % interval === 0) {
  console.info('Found it!');
  console.info('Minutes:', difference);
  console.info('Intervals:', difference / interval);
} else {
  console.error('Not found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works by:
 - Turning the time strings into numeric minutes (with `countOfMinutes()`)
 - Subtracting `startTime` from `specificTime` (and adjusting if we increment past 12:00)
 - Dividing the result by `minsPerIncrement` and checking whether the remainder is zero

```js
// The big payoff -- calculates whether we exactly hit `specificTime`
function isExact(start, specific, increment){
  let difference = countOfMinutes(specific) - countOfMinutes(start);
  if(difference <= 0){ difference += 12 * 60; } // Add 12 hours if necessary
  return difference % increment == 0;
}

// The converter -- because numbers are easier to divide than strings
function countOfMinutes(timeString){
  const hours = timeString.slice(0, timeString.indexOf(":"));
  const mins = timeString.slice(timeString.indexOf(":") + 1);
  return hours * 60 + mins;
}

// The results -- some readable output
function report(){
  console.log(`
     Repeatedly adding ${minsPerIncrement} to ${startTime} will eventually yield ${specificTime}?:
     _ ${isExact(startTime, specificTime, minsPerIncrement)} _`);
}

// The pudding -- a couple of test cases
let start, specific, minsPerIncrement;

startTime = "12:30"; specificTime = "3:55"; minsPerIncrement = 21;
report();

startTime = "4:20"; specificTime = "11:45"; minsPerIncrement = 5;
report();

startTime = "11:45"; specificTime = "4:20"; minsPerIncrement = 5;
report();
```